# Using Entry's file attachment in a Keepass trigger

Tags: automation, keepass

I'd like to create a trigger to copy a file attachement of one my entry to be copied to disk upon KeePass2.x DB Opening

The [triggers manual](https://keepass.info/help/v2/triggers.html) says: *trigger field can point to the data using a [field reference](https://keepass.info/help/base/fieldrefs.html)*.

Field Reference Manual explains the syntax to retrieve a *"password"* of *"my entry"*':
`{REF:P@T:my entry}`

I'd like to be able to do something like:
**file**: `%comspec%`
**Argument**: `/c copy {REF:F:my_file.txt@T:My Entry title} C:\destination`

Answer (score 1):

The KeePass team told me that it could be done by KPScript file but you need knowledge in C++ and the KeePass internals

So what I ended up doing is to create a new entry with the content of the file in `Notes` and the destination path in `URL` and my trigger is
file: `powershell.exe`
Argument:

```
-Command "Set-Content '{REF:A@I:4EADD152156165924CD9246A651D}' '{REF:N@I:4EADDB3BD09E0456416514CD9246A651D}'"
```